# How to edit the final "Finish order"-Button in Mage2?

Tags: magento2

We want to add a Google Analytics Code to the "Finish Order"-Button in the Magento2 Checkout. So far I've not been able to get the HTML structure for the corresponding buttons.

How can I add custom HTML code to the checkout buttons?

Comment: I'm confused about "Finish Order" button? Where's our "Finish Order" button? You can take a screenshoot?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I'm talking about this button: http://i.imgur.com/d3vGdvo.png